# NULL, then any other value in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.7. Given a table of vehicles, and a table of alerts, with a 1:N relationship. A vehicle could have no alerts, or multiple alerts in a mixture of closed and open states. If `alert.closed_time` is `NULL`, the alert is considered 'OPEN'.

To collapse all alerts to a single status value for each vehicle prioritising 'OPEN' alerts, I have been doing the following:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN a.closed_time IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0) END) > 0 THEN 'OPEN'
    ELSE 'CLOSED'
  END AS a.status,
  v.id
FROM alerts a JOIN vehicles v ON a.vehicle_id = v.id
GROUP BY v.id;
```

Which seems to be working OK. However, it strikes me there ought to be a simpler/more efficient way than nested CASE statements! It's important that if there is any `NULL` value in the column, I prioritise it over any timestamps. I did wonder about something like:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(a.closed_time, 'ACTIVE'))
```

and then looking for strings containing 'ACTIVE' in the column, but I'm not sure that's any better.

Comment: Unclear. Provide some sample data (as textual CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO or as online fiddle, skip unrelated columns) with all possible data combinations, and desired output for it.

Comment: `.. WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN a.closedTime IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0) END) > 0 THEN ..` contains excess code. Use `.. WHEN SUM(a.closedTime IS NULL) THEN ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you ultimately need to translate a datetime value into a string, I don't think it's possible with a single function call. However, you could simplify things a bit by using a conditional MAX() to return `1` if there are *any* open alerts, otherwise `0`. Then use IF() to translate the boolean result into the statuses: "OPEN" or "CLOSED"

```
SELECT
  IF(MAX(a.closedTime IS NULL) = 1, 'OPEN', 'CLOSED') AS status
  , v.id
FROM alerts a JOIN vehicles v ON a.vehicle_id = v.id
GROUP BY v.id
ORDER BY v.id
```

Results:

| status | id |
| --- | --- |
| OPEN | 1 |
| CLOSED | 2 |
| OPEN | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=dbb7d3439ff78a80eddd5076b64774da)*